# How to create a monad in GHC 7.10 or newer

Tags: haskell

In the book "Haskell programming from first principles" it is said that:

> If you are using GHC 7.10 or newer, you’ll see an Applicative
> constraint in the deﬁnition of Monad, as it should be:
>
> ```
> class Applicative m => Monad m where
>     (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
>     (>>) :: m a -> m b -> m b
>     return :: a -> m a
> ```

I have created the following applicative functor.

```
data WhoCares a = ItDoesnt | Matter a | WhatThisIsCalled deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor WhoCares where
    fmap _ ItDoesnt = ItDoesnt
    fmap _ WhatThisIsCalled = WhatThisIsCalled
    fmap f (Matter a) = Matter (f a)

instance Applicative WhoCares where
    pure = Matter
    Matter f <*> Matter a = Matter (f a)

main = do

    -- fmap id == id
    let funcx = fmap id "Hi Julie"
    let funcy = id "Hi Julie"
    print(funcx)
    print(funcy)
    print(funcx == funcy)

    -- fmap (f . g) == fmap f . fmap g
    let funcx' = fmap ((+1) . (*2)) [1..5]
    let funcy' = fmap (+1) . fmap (*2) $ [1..5]
    print(funcx')
    print(funcy')
    print(funcx' == funcy')

    -- pure id <*> v = v
    print(pure id <*> (Matter 10))

    -- pure (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w = u <*> (v <*> w)
    let appx = pure (.) <*> (Matter (+1)) <*> (Matter (*2)) <*> (Matter 10)
    let appy = (Matter (+1)) <*> ((Matter (*2)) <*> (Matter 10))
    print(appx)
    print(appy)
    print(appx == appy)

    -- pure f <*> pure x = pure (f x)
    let appx' = pure (+1) <*> pure 1 :: WhoCares Int
    let appy' = pure ((+1) 1) :: WhoCares Int
    print(appx')
    print(appy')
    print(appx' == appy')

    -- u <*> pure y = pure ($ y) <*> u
    let appx'' = Matter (+2) <*> pure 2
    let appy'' = pure ($ 2) <*> Matter (+ 2)
    print(appx'')
    print(appy'')
    print(appx'' == appy'')
```

Due to lack of examples, I am not understanding how to implement `>>=` and `>>`. The code I came up with so far is:

```
instance Monad (WhoCares a) where
    (>>=) :: Matter a -> (a -> Matter b) -> Matter b
    (>>) :: Matter a -> Matter b -> Matter b
    return :: a -> Matter a
    return = pure
```

So, that I can do stuff like:

```
half x = if even x
            then Matter (x `div` 2)
            else ItDoesnt

incVal :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> WhoCares a
incVal x
    | x + 1 <= 10 = return (x + 1)
    | otherwise = ItDoesnt

decVal :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> WhoCares a
decVal x
    | x - 1 >= 0 = return (x - 1)
    | otherwise = ItDoesnt

main = do
    print (Matter 7 >>= incVal >>= incVal >>= incVal)
    print (Matter 7 >>= incVal >>= incVal >>= incVal >>= incVal)
    print (Matter 7 >>= incVal >>= incVal >>= incVal >>= incVal >>= decVal >>= decVal)
    print (Matter 2 >>= decVal >>= decVal >>= decVal)
    print(Matter 20 >>= half >>= half)
```

With Output:

```
10
ItDoesnt
ItDoesnt
ItDoesnt
5
```

Please help.

Comment: Note `Matter f <*> Matter a = Matter (f a)` does not handle all cases, e.g. `ItDoesnt <*> WhatThisIsCalled` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

How to implement a monad instance for a given data type is in general not answerable without concrete information for how you want that instance to behave – there can be multiple valid instances for a single type.

For this example though, I see only one way: make it behave like the equivalent form

```
data ItIsCalled = ItDoesn't | WhatThisIsCalled
newtype WhoCares a = WhoCares { caresWho :: Either ItIsCalled a }
```

So I suggest looking up [the `Monad (Either c)` instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/src/Data.Either.html#line-157) and basing yours on that. The difference is that the `Left` case corresponds to two different constructors of your type, so you need a clause for each of them.

Comment: I have added some more details about the sample output.

Comment: You're example doesn't use `WhatThisIsCalled`. Then it just boils down to `Maybe a`.

Answer (score 0):

OP Here. I have removed `WhatThisIsCalled`.

Now the solution looks like:

```
data WhoCares a = ItDoesnt | Matter a deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor WhoCares where
    fmap _ ItDoesnt = ItDoesnt
    fmap f (Matter a) = Matter (f a)

instance Applicative WhoCares where
    pure = Matter
    Matter f <*> Matter a = Matter (f a)
    ItDoesnt <*> _ = ItDoesnt
    _ <*> ItDoesnt = ItDoesnt

instance Monad WhoCares where
    return x = Matter x
    (Matter x) >>= k = k x
    ItDoesnt >>= _ = ItDoesnt

half x = if even x
            then Matter (x `div` 2)
            else ItDoesnt

incVal :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> WhoCares a
incVal x
    | x + 1 <= 10 = return (x + 1)
    | otherwise = ItDoesnt

decVal :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> WhoCares a
decVal x
    | x - 1 >= 0 = return (x - 1)
    | otherwise = ItDoesnt

main = do
    -- fmap id == id
    let funcx = fmap id "Hi Julie"
    let funcy = id "Hi Julie"
    print(funcx)
    print(funcy)
    print(funcx == funcy)

    -- fmap (f . g) == fmap f . fmap g
    let funcx' = fmap ((+1) . (*2)) [1..5]
    let funcy' = fmap (+1) . fmap (*2) $ [1..5]
    print(funcx')
    print(funcy')
    print(funcx' == funcy')

    -- pure id <*> v = v
    print(pure id <*> (Matter 10))

    -- pure (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w = u <*> (v <*> w)
    let appx = pure (.) <*> (Matter (+1)) <*> (Matter (*2)) <*> (Matter 10)
    let appy = (Matter (+1)) <*> ((Matter (*2)) <*> (Matter 10))
    print(appx)
    print(appy)
    print(appx == appy)

    -- pure f <*> pure x = pure (f x)
    let appx' = pure (+1) <*> pure 1 :: WhoCares Int
    let appy' = pure ((+1) 1) :: WhoCares Int
    print(appx')
    print(appy')
    print(appx' == appy')

    -- u <*> pure y = pure ($ y) <*> u
    let appx'' = Matter (+2) <*> pure 2
    let appy'' = pure ($ 2) <*> Matter (+ 2)
    print(appx'')
    print(appy'')
    print(appx'' == appy'')

    -- m >>= return = m
    let monx = Matter 20 >>= return
    let mony = Matter 20
    print(monx)
    print(mony)
    print(monx == mony)

    -- return x >>= f = f x
    let monx' = return 20 >>= half
    let mony' = half 20
    print(monx')
    print(mony')
    print(monx' == mony')

    -- (m >>= f) >>= g = m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)
    let monx'' = return 20 >>= half >>= half
    let mony'' = half 20 >>= half
    print(monx'')
    print(mony'')
    print(monx'' == mony'')

    print (Matter 7 >>= incVal >>= incVal >>= incVal)
    print (Matter 7 >>= incVal >>= incVal >>= incVal >>= incVal)
    print (Matter 7 >>= incVal >>= incVal >>= incVal >>= incVal >>= decVal >>= decVal)
    print (Matter 2 >>= decVal >>= decVal >>= decVal)
    print (Matter 20 >>= half >>= half)
```

Comment: Right. This is now the same as `Maybe`, up to renaming.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I had to remove `WhatThisIsCalled` because I did not know how to implement it. If you write an answer with `WhatThisIsCalled`, taking this answer as an template then I will be glad to accept that.

Comment: As I already wrote in my answer, the only way to deal with `WhatThisIsCalled` is to treat it and `ItDoesn't` both as “failure cases”, i.e. instead of a single constructor equivalent to `Nothing` you have two, equivalent to `Left A` and `Left B`. So, basically just copy all the clauses dealing with `ItDoesn't` and change them to `WhatThisIsCalled`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I know, you know because you said "This is now the same as `Maybe`". I am really new in Haskell. I copied the maybe code. The things you are telling me sounds very abstract to me. If you do not give me code that I can run, it will not work for me (by playing with the code, i will understand more, but from theory i will not be able to create the code). So, I will be glad if you can kindly modify your answer with `WhatThisIsCalled`, taking this answer as an template.